# Load image from another assembly's resx file in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two assemblies, say assembly1 and assembly2.

In assembly2 there is a XAML file. In this XAML file I want to create an image.

What I want to do is setting the source of this image to a bitmap that is in a resx file from assembly1.

```
<Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="???" />
```

How do I correctly reference to that bitmap file in XAML? Is there an easy "XAML-only" solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I assume there is no thing such as an "XAML-only" solution.

Instead, I do it like this after the WPF control's Loaded event is called:

```
Assembly coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (otherAssembly.Resources));
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("otherAssembly.Resources", coreAssembly);

// get image from core resources
Bitmap completeImage = (Bitmap) resourceManager.GetObject("Complete");

// apply image to WPF image
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
completeImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
bitmapImage.EndInit();

this.myWpfImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```